# Facet_Wrap labels in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I'm trying to change labels for ggplot graph with facets, and am using a variable from the dataframe which is not faceted. The code is as belows-

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(lbl = mean(Petal.Length)) %>%
  select(lbl) %>%
  unlist() -> lbls
lbls <- map2(unique(iris$Species), lbls, paste, sep = "\n")
iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, group = 1)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ Species, labeller = lbls)
```

However, this gives me the following error-

```
Error in cbind(labels = list(), list(`{`, if (!is.null(.rows) || 
!is.null(.cols)) { : 
 number of rows of matrices must match (see arg 2)
```

I've looked at the labeller function and different options but most of them seem to be for variables which are included in facets. Is there a way this can be done? Any leads appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

From the documentation on `?labeller`, `labeller` can also be a named character vector. Note that we need to wrap the character vector in the `labeller` function. Also from looking at the examples in the help file, we need to pass the facetting variable `Species` as the argument to `labeller`. Thus the call should look something like:

`labeller = labeller(Species = setNames(unlist(lbls), unique(iris$Species)))`

The code should then be:

```
iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, group = 1)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ Species, labeller = labeller(Species = setNames(unlist(lbls), unique(iris$Species))))
```

Also, a much cleaner way to create the labels would be without `map2`:

`lbls <- setNames(paste(unique(iris$Species), lbls, sep = "\n"), unique(iris$Species))`

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works great! I missed the wrap part as well as passing the faceting variable. I think I should spend more time reading the docs for this

Comment: @MridulGarg the labeller functions and docs can certainly be confusing. Especially if you decide to use your own function rather than a named vector

Answer (score 6):

You could create a new facetting column on the fly and avoid `labeller` pain:

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  mutate(label = paste0(Species, "\n", round(mean(Petal.Length),2))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, group = 1)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~ label)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this but I'm already creating a new column for faceting so this won't work out for me. The iris example was just to reproduce the issue I was facing, but I appreciate your reply!

Comment: You can still use this method. Just create a label column by pasting your new facet column to the mean of whatever column your using for the mean.